# Magento - Extending Topmenu.php block stops the topmenu.phtml template loading

Tags: php, magento

I'm extending app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php with the following xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Menu>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Custom_Menu>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my class definition:

```
class Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
{

}
```

Even with my class not overriding any methods, the following template file just doesn't get processed:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml
```

I'm not overriding the template file.

As soon as I disable my module, it starts working again.

Do I need to declare anything else in my xml file?

Comment: Have you tried enabling developer mode and display_errors in the index.php file?
Is your file located in the correct place too? */Custom/Menu/Block/Page/Html/Topmenu.php

Answer (score 4):

Do this change in your config.xml file

```
<html_topmenu>Custom_Menu_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
```

and change your class name to

```
class Custom_Menu_Block_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing springs to mind. You may have your class file in the wrong place.  Your rewrite code looks correct, so when Magento instantiates a `page/html_topmenu` block it correctly resolves it to your `Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu` class name.  However, Magento may not be able to find the class `Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu`.  Try running the code

```
$block = new Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu;
var_dump($block);
```

from an empty controller and/or bootstrap file to ensure that Magento can find your class.  It also wouldn't hurt to run

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('page/html_topmenu');
var_dump($block);
```

To ensure your rewrite is doing what it needs to do.

Comment: There seems to be something very odd happening. Everything loads fine on my development server but not on my local machine. It must be environment differences with the LAMP installs and nothing to do with my code.

Comment: @MacroMan - I've had issues between environments before when mistakenly the case of a directory or file was different. Example: Custom/Menu/Block/Page/Html/TopMenu.php != Custom/Menu/Block/Page/Html/Topmenu.php

Comment: To elaborate further: I name my class Custom_Menu_Block_Page_Html_TopMenu but the file is at Custom/Menu/Block/Page/Html/Topmenu.php 
Magento searches for "TopMenu.php" but the file is actually "Topmenu.php". Some environments handle the difference in case, but some do not.

Comment: @JamieChong That's why you'll see a lot of developers avoid inter and camel casing in class name segments.